# Java Interprocess Communication

Tags: java, ipc

I have a situation where i need to send commands to a running java application, now i am using tcp/ip socket to send commands to the application using a internet explorer context menu item. But as soon as the application starts virus scanners complain that the application started listening, although i am only listening for local connections. I think this may be confusing to the users. I am looking at others ways of communicating without pissing off av scanners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you're best off a file based FIFO queue.  Or using Java Native Access/Java Native Interface to write to a NamedPipe or Shared Memory.  If you go the JNA/JNI route, you could create a [Named Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396%28VS.85%29.aspx).

But there's probably no way to do what you want, with any amount of efficiency without going the JNA/JNI route.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Java Management Extentions (JMX)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/index.html) to expose methods in a running process through a simple web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are pretty much the traditional way of doing IPC, but if you *really* want to avoid them, you *might* be able to come up with a workaround using the local filesystem.  You wouldn't want to use standard file reads/writes, since you would most likely want to effectively implement a queue in the filesystem.

If *I* were going to implement IPC through the filesystem, I'd probably use SQLite ([which can be threadsafe when compiled so)](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) and have one table for each listener.  I'd probably use a single-column table to insert the message, and the listener would just pull out the row with the lowest [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), then delete said row.

But my approach is not at all Java-specific, so there might be better ways to do that using Java (such as @darthcoder's response).