# java static variables

Tags: java

i have two java files  file1 and file2 as follows in package pak

file1:

```
package pak;
public  class file1 {
  public  static int x=432;

  public static void main(String[]  args){
    System.out.println("y is "+file2.y);
    while(x==432) {
      System.out.println("x is "+file1.x);
    }

  }
}
```

file 2:

```
package pak;
public  class file2 {
  public  static int y=46;
  public static void main(String[]  args){

   System.out.println("x is "+file1.x);
   ++file1.x;
   System.out.println("x is "+file1.x);

  }
}
```

i will run first file1 and it will be running and when i run file 2 from another shell  it should increment x value and it should come out of loop in file 1 
can some one pls help me ??????

Comment: You need to learn about *Interprocess Communication* (IPC) - it's not as simple as what you are trying to do.

Comment: When you say that you use 2 shell... it also means you have 2 separate process, right? In that case static variable are not shared between file1 and file2.

Comment: then how do i do it ?in any other way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i will run killjava that kills the process in iostat.java and just before killing i need to perform one action

You can do this with a shutdown hook.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Final stats");
        }
    }));
    System.out.println("PID " + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("stats");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

prints

```
PID 29490@plus-dev-01
stats
stats
stats
stats
stats
Final stats
```

The last line occurs after I run `kill 29490` in another window.

---

> how will i do it for two different processes

This is a complex answer with too many possible solution to mention. (Shared memory, JMS, RMI, signals, Sockets, IPC etc)

Generally, this is done as a high level concept like "stop process" rather than "increment x" even if the result is the same.

The problem is that as its an advanced topic, you would need to have a good understand of interprocess communication to understand the full answer.

The simple solution is; don't do it, find another way to do what you want.

Comment: is it not possible in any simple way ??

Comment: There is a simple way, use one JVM. ;) Its not clear from your example why you would want to use multiple processes.

Comment: actually in my project i will running iostat.java ffrom one shell ...it will be generating logs ...and from another shell i will run killjava that kills the process in iostat.java and just before killing i need to perform one action (i.e record the logs avg ,min,max) in one csv file ....

Answer (score 2):

It won't work in such a simple way. Either you

- run the code currently within your two `main` methods from two distinct threads within the same process (i.e. Java app), (and you also need to declare `file1.x` `volatile` for this to work), or
- run the two distinct processes as described above, but then you need to make them communicate with each other, which is far from trivial. Otherwise the two processes each will have their own copies of `file1.x` so modifications in one won't be visible for the other.

Comment: how will i do it for two different processes

Comment: As Nim mentioned, this is a topic called Interprocess Communication (IPC). I have no direct experience with it so can't help you more than giving a few links: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Finterpro.htm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416780/java-interprocess-communication

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking two different jvm processes. Both the processes will have it's own copy of `file1` and `file2`. Change in static variable within one process will not be seen by other process.